# Help for Maps and locations

Tags: maps, here, windows-mobile

*Lumia 930 with WP 8.1*
I want add a location to Here Maps by **langitude** and **altitude** cordinate.
How to Ican do it? Is there a way or app that do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can enter it using Drive+. You will have to find the NE coordinates from your longitude and altitude and feed them to you Drive+ app.

Comment: latitude and longitude, not altitude...